# CommonsMultiPartFile upload - uploading more bytes than actual bytes of file

Tags: spring, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServiceResponse<VoidData> uploadStateTaxDocument(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file)
{
    try
    {
        writeStreamInFile(file.getInputStream());
        return responseBuilderV3.buildSuccess(VoidData.VOID, HttpCode.OK);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private void writeStreamInFile(InputStream input)
{
    try
    {
        File targetFile = new File("/tmp/test_upload_file.pdf");
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(input, targetFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read file: ", ex);
    }
}
```

I want to upload files and then saving in server. It's workign fine for 3-4KB files. Successfully uploading but, if the file is more than 500KB then it is not working. Uploaded file is empty and more KBs than actual size.
I am uploading a 807 KB file..uploaded size is 1.4MB and uploaded file is empty.

Java version - Java 8

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`CommonsMultipartResolver` is injected in spring file.

Any idea why it is happening.

Comment: Write directly to disk, don't first convert it to a `byte[]`.

Comment: I need bytes bcs before writing to file I am going to encrypt the so need bytes to encrypt.

Comment: If you encrypt stuff why shouldn't the size change? You are modifying the file and expect the file size to remain the same?! That is weird.

Comment: Encypt part is not added yet. Before encryption itself uploaded file size is more.

Comment: You are also writing everything and always to the same files.

Comment: tried directly writing inputStream to file also....still file size is more and empty file, see code changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152751/discussion-between-raj-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Instead of `CommonsMulitpartFile` use `MultipartFile` and use `MultipartFile.transferTo(targetFile)`.